# Header is repeating after span added

Tags: jquery

I believe the issue is because the JS is applying to all the elements on the page at the same time, and not one at a time, but I'm not 100% how to resolve that.

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/oyg9mLad/

```
<h2>This is your title</h2>

<h2>This is your title</h2>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var subheader = $('h2'),
        subheadertext = $(subheader).text(),
        subheaderfull = '<span>' + subheadertext + '</span>';

    $(subheader).html(subheaderfull);
});
```

Comment: And what are you *trying* to do with that code?

Comment: What is the question, actually?

Comment: You have selected 2 `h2` elements, so when you get the `text()` of both of them it is appended together, hence `subheadertext` = `This is your titleThisis your title`. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this code so I can't really help you any more than that.

Comment: When you say $('h2'), it will select all the `<h2>` tags from your page, and when you say $('h2').text(), will append all the text of all `<h2>` tags. that's why its repeating the text `This is your titleThis is your title`
Learn more about jQuery selector here.
http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to alter the content of each 'h2' element in your page you should use `$.each`:

```
$.each($('h2'), function() { /* your code here */  });
```

See the updated jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/oyg9mLad/5/.

I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Adding a span around certain H2s to put the grey bar behind them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only the first `h2` try this:

```
var subheader = $('h2:first')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oyg9mLad/4/)